# What are sprays?

Tags: overwatch

In Overwatch there are unlockable items called Sprays, that along with skins and poses, change something about your character.

However, I have no idea what they do. Skins and Poses are pretty straightforward, but what are sprays for? I was thinking it was an add on for the skin you choose, like a decal, but I can't see it displayed anywhere on the body.

What are they for and what do they do?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A spray is a graffiti-like tag that you can place onto the environment for other players to see.

The default keybinding is <kbd>T</kbd>, or D-Pad Up on console.

Screenshot via [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/3tduyh/realised_i_could_spray_the_overwatch_logo_using_t/):

[image: spray]

Comment: Whoah, I didn't even think that was a possibility.

Comment: Incidentally, sprays have been a part of multiplayer shooters going back to at least Half-Life 1: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2885-IHML-0750

Answer (score 4):

Sprays are icons that you can tag on walls and such. Some are unique to each hero, while others can be used by any hero. The icon that will be tagged can be selected from the owned tags available to that hero. According to this [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/3tduyh/realised_i_could_spray_the_overwatch_logo_using_t/) you apply sprays by pushing "T", and it [seems](http://blizzardwatch.com/2016/02/11/overwatch-loot-boxes-cosmetic-rewards/) you have to be relatively close to a wall to use it.

Comment: I'm curious in how far you consider them customizable.

Comment: @Zaibis you can choose which one you want to use of the ones you unlock.

Comment: So it customizes my character/player. But as you wrote it it reads for me that you can customize the icons itself.

Comment: @Zaibis I'll see if I can't edit that to clear that up

Answer (score 0):

You press T to place or spray a mark you have set.

You can change it when character editing. Some sprays are for specific characters. You unlock sprays in loot boxes