# What happens when you reach the 25th spray?

Tags: overwatch

I've got 24 of 25 sprays for one of my heroes.

I was just about to get the 25th but I'm not sure which one to choose, and also I'm not sure what the consequences will be, if I pick the 25th spray will I be able to get any more for that hero?

I'm trying to get the "Decked Out" achievement by unlocking 50 unlocks, but I like spraying, so I don't want to waste that last spray if it turns out to be my last one on that hero.

What happens when you reach the 25th spray? is the limit that you can get or the limit for the "Decked Out" achievement?

Comment: I think I might know what you're asking about after reading the answers, but this question seriously needs some context.

Comment: see [what are sprays](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/264457/what-are-sprays)

Comment: You can keep collecting the rest of the sprays. As @VanBuzzKill pointed out the 25 spray count refers to the specific character sprays but the other sprays will still be collectable after you hit the 25/25 mark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting all 25 for a character means you have all 25 *character specific* sprays. Yes there are many more than 25 sprays you can select but the rest are general ones received from achievements mainly, and don't count towards that hero's "unlocks", or the "Decked Out" achievement (Origin Edition skins also do not count in this regard).

Comment: Expanding on the last sentence, this means they also do not count towards the Decked Out achievement. Neither do the Origins Edition skins, I had to get 51 items on Pharah before getting her achievement. (I am currently on 55/56, I just need the golden gun for 100% Pharah)

Comment: Might want to be explicit and mention that you can keep collecting the rest of the sprays and there are no limits on the number of sprays you can have.

It sounds like the OP is confused and thinks you can only get 25 sprays in total per character and the game will stop you from collecting the rest.

Answer (score 0):

If you open a loot box, and you already own one or more of the items in the loot box, you will receive 20% of the duplicate items' value in currency. A spray is worth 25 credits, so unboxing a duplicate spray will give you 5 credits.

Comment: OP seems to be asking about whether or not characters can only choose from a maximum of 25 sprays once unlocked, nothing about getting duplicate sprays.